# Rails controller action redirect_to refresh page

Tags: ruby-on-rails, redirect, controller, action

I want my page to refresh once a record has been created, at the moment it directs it to the page before. here is the code from my controller:

```
def create
@license = License.new(params[:license])

respond_to do |format|
  if @license.save
    format.html { redirect_to :controller => 'customers', :action => 'index' }
    format.json { render json: @customer, status: :created, location: @customer }
  else
    format.html { render action: "new" }
    format.json { render json: @customer.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
  end

end
```

where it says `redirect_to` i need that to refresh, or link to the current page, with the current id, which would be `:controller => 'customers', :action => 'show'` but with the id of the current page's record.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try

```
redirect_to customer_path(@license.id)
```

instead.

Depending on what your routes.rb file says, it should work.

But if it doesn't, try:

```
redirect_to show_customer_path(@license.id)
```

However, here I have to assume that somehow, your customers_controller.rb is somehow showing records from the License model. If License and Customer are separate models, you will have to find the customer_id in some other way.

Perhaps, it is:

```
redirect_to customer_path(@license.customer_id)
```

If License is not connected to Customer in any way, you will need to pass it in as part of the post request.

Comment: `redirect_to customer_path(@license.customer_id)` did the job :) thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Try,
I think you are passing customer_id to on params(Licensee belongs to customer), if so then
 `redirect_to customer_path(@license.customer)` or `redirect_to customer_path(params[:customer_id])`